# How do exactly mean multi vendor in magento?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, multistore, multi-vendor

I am using magento CE 1.7.0.2 and now i am getting confuse in multi vendor system, i am not clear about munti vendor and how can i manage it. I have to manage multi store where products will be store wise.

So can i manage products store wise and define vendor for it ? I didn't get any relational answer from google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain,
Multivendor and Multi store set up both are different words.

Multi vendor is like amazon, ebay, flipkart where different sellers upload their products to sell.

Multi Store: Magento provides functionality of multi store set up. You can set up store for multi language and other purpose. (Dropdown to change the store view)

Multi website : Magento also offers Multi website set up where 2 websites can run on one Magento. (Domain can be different)

Comment: Ok, is mult store display products store wise ? and how can i set for multi vendor and multisote. ?

Comment: Yes, you can set up products by store view. You will need to select the store view from product edit page to display. 
Multi vendor :You can look for the Magento extension for marketplace multi vendor extension on google.

Comment: Ok, thank you but i want to display new products in each store and new products will be different store wise ! how can i manage it ? can you please give me direction ?

Comment: You might looking for this, Right?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650000/magento-get-product-collection-filter-by-store-id

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069318/magento-addstorefilter-not-working

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302996/magento-get-all-product-collection-in-admin-controller-by-store-ids

Answer (score 1):

You can use Frontend multi-vendor environment (marketplace) like Ebay , where Each vendor will have option to upload product in their my account section or elsewhere in frontend for that You can use plugings like Webkul marketplace , dropship marketplace 
Second type is using Magento ACL where each vendor will have its own Admin panel with limited access and a store , you can look for advance permissions plugin to achieve it